# Randint não gera números aleatórios na segunda vez que eu o utilizo

Tags: python, random, números-aleatórios

Meu randint quando usado pela segunda vez ele não gera novos números aleatórios, ele permanece com os mesmos números gerados. Eu sei que em C quando isso acontece eu posso usar o **srand(time(NULL));** , porém no Python eu não estou achando nada parecido

Mostrar 3 matrizes distintas

```
from random import randint

matriz = [[], [], []]


def gerar_matriz ():
    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        for i in range(0, 3):

            s = randint(0, 9)
            matriz[c].append(s)    # adiciona os números a matriz


for c in range(3):

    gerar_matriz()

    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            print(matriz[c][i], end=' ')
        print(' ')

    print ('\n')
```

Comment: o randint em seu uso normal gera números aleatórios sim. Por favor poste o código de como você está fazendo. (usar o valor de de time como seed do rand funcionaria, mas acho que você está errando em algo mais fundamental)

Comment: Eu postei o código

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você não está criando matrizes novas em cada chamada a `gerar_matriz()` - o que você faz é acrescentar novos números ao final de cada linha já existente.

E na hora de imprimir as linhas, você usou um tamanho fixo de 3, então vê sempre os três primeiros elementos da linha.É só trocar o seu for interno de impressão pra ver o que está acontecendo:

```
    ...
    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        for i in range(0, len(matriz[0])):  # alterei esta linha
            print(matriz[c][i], end=' ')
        print(' ')
```

Por isso que boas práticas de programação em geral pedem que façamos tudo dentro de funções - o seu código que cria uma matriz nova e que chama a geração de matrizes está fora de funções e não pode ser executado de forma a isolar a matriz, que é uma variável global.

Se você fizer assim, vai funcionar:

```
from random import randint

def gerar_matriz ():
    matriz = [[], [], []]

    for c in range(len(matriz)):
        for i in range(0, 3):

            s = randint(0, 9)
            matriz[c].append(s)    # adiciona os números a matriz
    return matriz

    def imprime():

        for c in range(3):

            matriz = gerar_matriz()

            for c in range(len(matriz)):
                for i in range(0, 3):
                    print(matriz[c][i], end=' ')
                print(' ')
        print ('\n')

    imprime()
```

Só o que fiz aí foi deixar de depender da "matriz" como uma variável global - ela é criada dentro da função gerar_matriz e retornada para quem chamou a função. (transformar o código de impressão numa função não é essencial, mas evita que o nome "matriz" seja de novo associado globalmente, e que outras funções eventualmetne fossem ver somente a última matriz gerada).

Uma outra coisa é que em Python raramente, raramente mesmo, se precisa usar `for` com `range`. Em geral estamos interessados nos elementos de uma sequência, não nos índices dos elementos, para depois buscar os elementos.

No caso da matriz, podemos fazer um `for` para obter cada linha, e dentro um `for` para obter cada elemento:

```
def imprime():

    for c in range(3):  # aqui sim, queremos repetir algo 3 vezes!
        matriz = gerar_matriz()

        for linha in matriz:
            for elemento in linha:
                print(elemento, end=' ')
            print()
    print ('\n')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda